# Send Email Once Certain Criteria Met

Tags: javascript, html, email

I need to build a page for my website where only people with the correct Verification Code can request a Username and Password.  Here is my code this far.

```
<form action="MAILTO:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
First Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="First" value=""><br>
Last Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="Last" value=""><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail" value=""><br>
Desired Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="Username" value="" size="16"><br>
Desired Password:<br>
<input type="text" name="Password" value="" size="16"><br>
Verification Number:<br>
<input type="text" name="VerifyID" value="" size="6"><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

I would prefer a JavaScript code to only allow emails with the verification code "053198" to send.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It would be highly unwise to do this with javascript: anybody looking at the code for your page could figure out what your verification code is. Or they could just change the page to remove your check. You need to check the verification code on the server, where users can't inspect it.

Comment: It doesn't need to be too terribly secure.  I am going to obfuscated just as an added measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is a simple example:**

Add `onsubmit` and an `ID` to the `form` tag:

```
<form id="myForm" action="" onsubmit="myFunction()">
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
     var x=document.forms["myForm"]["VerifyID"].value;
    if (x == "053198"){
        alert("success");
        return true;
    } else{
        alert("failed");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Note:** This is not the most secure way since the user can view the page source and get the verification code.

**UPDATE**

You could use window.location.href = "mailto:mail@domain.com"; in the `if` statement and remove `mailto` from the `form` tag.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fb5dL/)**

Comment: I need it to not open Outlook if the number is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, haven't had time to check until today.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should validate this on the server side as well. However, you can validate on the client side with something like:

Add an ID to your verification field and a click event to your submit button.

```
<input type="text" name="VerifyID" id="VerifyID" value="" size="6"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="return verify();">
```

Use the following javascript:

```
<script>
var verify = function() {
   var verificationNumber = document.getElementById('VerifyID');
   return verificationNumber.value == '053198';
};
</script>
```

This is not a secure solution, however. Storing that number on the client side means that a bot can just grab it from your source. Far better to handle this on the server side.

Comment: And now my boss wants PHP or ASP.  Thanks for your help though!